# PHP mailer with html

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I am very new to PHP. I did a contact form using HTML and PHP and I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function eregi() in F:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\include\fgcontactform.php:548 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\include\fgcontactform.php(387): FGContactForm->validate_email('lyubo841@gmail....') #1 F:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\include\fgcontactform.php(129): FGContactForm->Validate() #2 F:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\contactform.php(26): FGContactForm->ProcessForm() #3 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\include\fgcontactform.php on line 548

I've been trying to fix it for hours but no success. I haven't provided any code because the code is long and don't know which part to provide.

Please assist and ask for the code if required.

Comment: If your php is 7.0 - than this function has been removed from it and you have to rewrite your code without it.

Comment: there is also no code here; just an error message.

Comment: If you trace this error to PHPailer, it means you are running a *really* old version and you should upgrade immediately - which may fix your problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

ereg_replace function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0. So you must have to use preg_replace() function instead of ereg_replace() Where You Define In The COde